# What does this Oracle TO_CHAR format do: "FM99990.90"

Tags: oracle

I have this number format and not able to find examples of how it will look. It is not listed on Oracle website. This below SQL is what I have and not sure what the result will look like since I don't have access to Oracle SQL at the moment to be able to run and see the result.

```
to_char(deductionAmount, 'FM99990.90')
```

Does anyone know? Deduction amount is in this format most likely: xx.xx

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734607/oracle-to-char-format-number-with-fill-mode-fm0000) is your answer.

Comment: Here's [access to Oracle SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a695516019d48673c0fa0c0c0045315) for you.

Comment: @mustaccio whats dual? is there sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is listed/documented.

[Format Model Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA)

> **FM**
>
> Fill mode. Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes to
>   fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the
>   display width of the largest element for the relevant format model:
>
> Numeric elements are padded with leading zeros to the width of the
>   maximum value allowed for the element. For example, the YYYY element
>   is padded to four digits (the length of '9999'), HH24 to two digits
>   (the length of '23'), and DDD to three digits (the length of '366').
>
> ...

Example:

```
SQL> select to_char(1.5, 'FM99990.90') from dual;

TO_CHAR(1
---------
1.50

SQL> select to_char(1.5, '99990.90') from dual;

TO_CHAR(1
---------
     1.50

SQL>
```